# Linear Algebra - Diagonalizable matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

It's a new topic we learn during the linear algebra class and I need a bit help understanding.
Lets say, for example, that I have this matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}2&1\\x&8\end{pmatrix}
and
x ∈ R

Can one tell me what may be x in order this matrix will be diagonalizable?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$ or over $\Bbb C$?

Comment: First of all, do you know when is a matrix diagonalizable in general?

Comment: over R and yes sir, I know in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of this matrix (denoted $A$) is
$$\chi_A(\lambda)=\det(A-\lambda I)=(2-\lambda)(8-\lambda)-x=\lambda^2-10\lambda+16-x$$
and the reduced discriminant of $\chi_A(\lambda)$ is
$$\Delta'=9+x$$
hence

- if $x>-9$ then there's two distinct real eigenvalues of $A$ and then it's diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$
- if $x<-9$ then there's two distinct complex eigenvalues of $A$ and then it's diagonalizable over $\Bbb C$ but not over $\Bbb R$.
- if $x=-9$ then the only eigenvalue is $\lambda=5$ but since $A\ne5 I$ then $A$ isn't diagonalizable.

Comment: Thank you! you helped a lot!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix is diagonalizable iff it has distinct eigenvalues.

For any $2\times 2$ matrix of the form \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix} ($a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$), the characteristic equation is $\det(\lambda I-A)=\lambda^2-(a+d)\lambda+ad-bc=0$. For the equation to have 2 distinct roots, the discriminant has to be greater than $0$. That is, $(a+d)^2-4(ad-bc)>0$. Simplification yields $-4bc<(a-d)^2$.

In your case, $a=2$, $b=1$, $c=x$ and $d=8$. So, $-4bc<(a-d)^2$ implies $-4x<36$. That is, $x>-9$.

Note: If you are considering $\mathbb{C}$, then $A$ is diagonalizable when $-4bc>(a-d)^2$.

Comment: Thank you! you helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
a real $2\times 2$ matrix is *not* diagonalizable $\iff$ it has no eigenvalues,
or only one eigenvalue and is not a multiple of the identity.

Comment: if so, then there is no x which can answer this question because this matrix is not diag. Am I right?

Comment: no. If you have 2 different eigenvalues, the matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: the answer: if x > -9, the matrix is diagonalizable, otherwise it is not.

Comment: I'm confused. Can you explain please what I should do in order to answer a question like that? Looking for eigenvalues?

Comment: - If M has no eigenvalue, it is not diagonalizable.

Comment: - If M has 2 real eigenvalues, it is diagonalizable (if $(v1, v2)$ are 2 eigenvectors with different values, $(v1,v2)$ is a basis).

Comment: - If M = L Id, is is diagonal...

Comment: - otherwise, if M were diagonalizable with 1 eigenvalue L, you could find $P$ invertible such as $M = P^ {-1} L\times Id P = L\times Id$. It is excluded.

Comment: Thank you! you helped a lot!